# Floating point is limited to 16 digits

Tags: ruby, numbers

I have the following code:

```
def pi
  pivalue =  4 * (4 * Math.atan(1.0/5.0) - Math.atan(1.0/239.0))
  pivaluestring = pi.to_s
  puts pivaluestring[0,20]
end
```

Why is that pivalue is only limited to 16 decimal points? I want there to be a much bigger limit (maximum).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [BigMath](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigMath.html) and [BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) (in the Standard Library):

```
require "bigdecimal/math"

p BigMath::PI(50).to_s
#=>"0.3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592309049629352442819E1"

# Or
include BigMath
p PI(100).to_s
```

BigDecimal provides arbitrary-precision floating point decimal arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby floats are 64bit floats. Once you take away the sign bit and the exponent bits you are left with 52 bits for the mantissa which is about 16 digits of decimal precision.

Ruby does have an arbitrary precision library: big decimal. Converting your code to use it would look a little like

```
require "bigdecimal"
require "bigdecimal/math"

def pi(prec=20)
  pivalue =  4 * (4 * BigMath.atan(BigDecimal.new("0.2",prec), prec) - BigMath.atan(BigDecimal.new(1)/BigDecimal.new(239), prec))
  pivaluestring = pivalue.to_s
  puts pivaluestring[0,20]
end
```

You usually have to give bigdecimal a precision to tell it how many decimals it has to track.

There is also a built in `BigMath.PI` function

Answer (score 0):

That is because `Math.atan` is a `Float`. Since you only have that much precision in the middle of the calculation, you cannot get more precision.

By the way, for float precision, you can get the pi simply by doing:

```
Math::PI # => 3.141592653589793
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to get an arbitrary length of pi. I was implementing the Machin-like formula. It seems I need to find another algorithm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Floating point values have limited precision based on the number of bits used to store the value. Read these articles about floating-point arithmetic and limitations:

http://floating-point-gui.de/

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Float.html